# Django admin search wildcard

Tags: django-admin

I want to add a support for `*` wildcard in my django admin site.
Currently, if I have an instance named `"abcde"`, and I search for it in the change list with `abc` (let's say I do an icontain filter) it will find a match.
However, when I use SQL wildcard `*` in the search field like: `a*c`, it finds nothing.
How can I add this wildcard support?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own `ModelAdmin.get_search_results` method to support this.

Have a look at this implementation snippet:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3005/

Answer (score 1):

We can by now (ca. 2017/Django 2.1) simply add filters like `__regex` or `__iregex` to the search field name and they will be picked up automatically by `ModelAdmin`. Depending on your database this gives you support to POSIX regexes like `.*` `^abc`, `(ab|cd)` and similar:

```py
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    search_fields = ("my_field__regex",)
```

See: [Django regex filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-regex), [relevant commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/244cc401559e924355cf943b6b8e66ccf2f6da3a)

PS: For true wildcard support you could then also override `get_search_results` in the above class to replace `*` in the search term with `.*`. (Don't know if I can recommend that though, probably has some weird edge cases):

```py
   def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        search_term = search_term.replace("*", ".*")
        return super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
```

Comment: the `__regex / __iregex` in `search_fields` trick is amazingly useful, thanks a ton!